# Making camera preview full-screen

Tags: flutter

I would like the camera preview screen to be full-screen, instead of the camera condensed down into a rectangle.

In other words, I would like the camera preview to cover the entire screen, and me build the elements on top of this. Not for the elements to reduce the camera preview.

Is there a specific element of code I need to add?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  Function setData;
  Camera({Key key, this.setData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<Camera> {
  CameraController controller;
  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIndex;
  String imgPath;
  var image;

  Future _openGallery() async {
    image = await controller.takePicture();
    if (widget.setData != null) {
      widget.setData(File(image.path));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
      cameras = availableCameras;

      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCameraIndex = 0;
        });
        _initCameraController(cameras[selectedCameraIndex]).then((void v) {});
      } else {
        print('No camera available');
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error :${err.code}Error message : ${err.message}');
    });
  }

  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }

      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {}
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: 120,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[_cameraControlWidget(context), Spacer()],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display Camera preview.
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Loading',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    }

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }

  /// Display the control bar with buttons to take pictures
  Widget _cameraControlWidget(context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.camera,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                // getImage();
                _openGallery();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Column widget puts widgets on top of each other vertically. Instead, you should use the Stack widget:

Something like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: 120,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[_cameraControlWidget(context), Spacer()],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Yup, what I came up with as well. Thanks!